# Imposing Shapes on Video Files Using Matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

Is it possible to impose a shape, let's say rectangle, on video files in Matlab ? I know that it is easily possible to do it on image files using shape inserter but couldn't find a way to do it on videos.

So far my best guess is to extract the frames, impose the rectangles and somehow encode it again into the stream. However, I wonder if there's a more elegant way to achieve it.

Comment: In MATLAB, this is the only way I know how to do it.

Comment: If @rayryeng says that thats the only way he knows to do it, and the question is related do CV, you can trust him. Most likely he is rigth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly the way you have to do it.

- read a frame of video using `vision.VideoFileReader`
- insert whatever annotations you need into the frame using `insertShape`, `insertMarker`, `insertText`, or `insertObjectAnnotation`
- write the modified frame out to a new video file using `vision.VideoFileWriter`
- repeat for all frames